# insert a value calculated from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to do a query for inserting a value calculated starting upon another table.
I don't want to use Temporary tables and I would like to do everything in one singel query.
It is possible?

I tried this one below but it doesn't work.

Thanks

AFeG

```
INSERT INTO MyTable( `DATE`, `Name`, `Total` ) 
VALUES ( 
 '2010/01/01',
 'Thunder',
  SELECT SUM(aValue) FROM AnotherTable
)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work?

What's the output of the query if you run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT  
INTO    MyTable( `DATE`, `Name`, `Total` ) 
SELECT  '2010/01/01', 'Thunder', SUM(aValue)
FROM    AnotherTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
insert mytable
select date
      ,name
      ,sum(total)
  from anothertable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want precisely what you indicated:

```
insert mytable
select 
"2010/01/01", "thunder", 
sum(mycolumn)
from othertable
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the INSERT INTO statement simply failed because the nested SELECT statement has to be enclosed in parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable( `DATE`, `Name`, `Total` ) 
VALUES ( 
 '2010/01/01',
 'Thunder',
  (SELECT SUM(aValue) FROM AnotherTable)
);
```