# Inserting output values into a column in sql developer

Tags: sql

I'm able to calculate the number of days stayed in by this command..

```
select trunc(DISCHARGE_DATE) - ADMISSION_DATE
from tblhotel;
```

However, I want to store this into another column in the same table. How can I use output of this to store into another column, lets say called 'days_stayed'.

Or can I use this as a constrain for that column?

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119374/insert-a-value-calculated-from-another-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblhotel (days_stayed)
VALUES (TRUNC(DISCHARGE_DATE) - ADMISSION_DATE);
```

This assumes you are inserting a single row. If you want to insert the value you calculated into the same row that you're calculating the data from in the SELECT query above, you'll need to use an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE tblhotel
SET days_stayed = TRUNC(DISCHARGE_DATE) - ADMISSION_DATE;
```

If you haven't god a days_stayed column in the table, you'll need to add one.

```
ALTER TABLE tblhotel ADD (days_stayed NUMERIC);
```

Hope this helps!

Edit:
However, I should mention that is generally bad database design to include calculated fields in your tables, as they add extra unneeded storage, and can cause data inconsistencies (among other reasons). It's usually better to calculate it as it's needed, so if you want to regularly get this value, I would suggest creating a stored procedure to get it, or creating a view on this table that gets it every time.
Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW tblhotels_view AS 
SELECT DISCHARGE_DATE, ADMISSION_DATE,
TRUNC(DISCHARGE_DATE) - ADMISSION_DATE AS DAYS_STAYED
FROM tblhotel;
```

You could add in whatever fields into the SELECT as needed. Then, you just need to query the tblhotels_view when you need this field:

```
SELECT * FROM tblhotels_view;
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked.. Just one question, can  I add such constraint that can calculate automatically for that field?

Comment: No problem. Do you mean that you want to automatically calculate that field and store in in the database without doing it manually? You could do it using triggers or procedures.
However, I should mention that is generally bad database design to include calculated fields in your tables, as they add extra unneeded storage, and can cause data inconsistencies (among other reasons). 
I've updated my answer above to include another option.